# How can I compare these two properties through Data Annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public Associate Associate { get; set; }

    public AssociateWeight AssociateWeight { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Confirm Weight")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a weight.")]
    [Compare("AssociateWeight.Weight", ErrorMessage = "Please enter identical weights.")]
    public decimal ConfirmWeight { get; set; }
}
```

The property `AssociateWeight` has a property called `Weight` that I would like to compare to `ConfirmWeight` to make sure they're equal.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to write your own validator. That said, you can't do that with "only" Data-annotations (not unless you flatten down the AssociateWeight and then use the normal CompareAttribute)

Comment: A view model is not a class for holding other models. It contains properties with you use in the view, so replace `public AssociateWeight AssociateWeight { get; set; }` with `public decimal Weight { get; set; }` (and include whatever other properties of `AssociateWeight` that you include in the view, then `[Compare("Weight", ...)]` will work as intended. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by custom validation

**Model**

```
[RegistrationValidation]
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public Associate Associate { get; set; }
    public AssociateWeight AssociateWeight { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Confirm Weight")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a weight.")]   
    public decimal ConfirmWeight { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom validation**

```
public class RegistrationValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        RegistrationViewModel app = value as RegistrationViewModel;
        if (app.AssociateWeight.weight != app.ConfirmWeight)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Please enter identical weights.";
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```